# Как передать данные из фрагмента в прежний фрагмент?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как передать данные из фрагмента в прежний фрагмент (из фрагмента В в  фрагмент А)? Вот мой код, но он даже не реагирует на получение данных. Чтобы убедиться в этом, я установил простое всплывающее уведомление.

Фрагмент А

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

  val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infos_trafic, container, false)
  buttonGoToB = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_B)      

  findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>("key")?.observe( 
  viewLifecycleOwner) { result -> Toast.makeText(this, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }

  buttonGoToB.setOnClickListener { goToB() }

  return view
}


private fun goToB()
{
    parentFragmentManager.commit{
        setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
        add(R.id.main_nav_host, FragmentB())
        addToBackStack(null)
    }
}
```

Фрагмент В

```
buttonBack.setOnClickListener {
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", "myString")
parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
}
```

Comment: А почему вы вручную на фрагмент менеджере фрагмент добавляете делаете и pop, а не используете navigation?

Comment: Я думаю этот метод проще, не нужно строить navigation. Может я не прав, т.к. я новичок в котлине и андроиде.

Comment: ну тогда и работать ничего не будет, что у вас и случилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение по [ссылке](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)

Фрагмент А

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
        // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
        val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
        // Do something with the result
    }
}
```

Фрагмент В

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val result = "result"
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to result))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы не хотите имено передавать между фрагментами bundle, так как вопрос можно решить общей ViewModel для этих фрагментов. Инициализируйте viewModel в активити, которой принадлежат эти фрагменты. Теперь в своих фрагментах сделайте следующее:

```
lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    activity?.let {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(it, defaultViewModelProviderFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

Теперь фрагментам доступно все, что есть в viewModel. Например можно инициализировать LiveData в вашей viewModel и подписаться на изменения во фрагментах.